# Typo3 PHP Strict Standards: Non-static method t3lib_div::getClassName()

Tags: typo3

When the website is requested following pops up in the error logs

> [Wed Oct 28 12:27:38.884831 2015] [:error] [pid 5245] [client
>   82.198.211.146:43605] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method t3lib_div::getClassName() should not be called statically in
>   /var/www/website.org/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php on line 5338

I already googled it and inserted this into `/typo3conf/localconf.php`

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['exceptionalErrors'] = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_WARNING ^ E_USER_ERROR ^ E_USER_NOTICE ^ E_USER_WARNING ^ E_STRICT;
```

But this didn't help. My typo3 version is 4.5 and my php version is 5.5.9-1. I am running my webservice on an apache2 server on ubuntu 14.04. Do you know why I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is that you are using an old TYPO3 version, which is not fully compatible to PHP 5.5. TYPO3 4.5 is at its end of life since March 2015. So updating TYPO3 would be the best solution.

Another, more immediate solution would be to set `error_reporting` in your `php.ini` to something excluding `E_STRICT`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)! Can this be also a reason why the file upload isn't working properly any more? We can upload smaller files but not rather larger files.

Comment: Check the settings in the install tool, and in php.ini the maximal upload size and the maximal post size.

Comment: At this point I know what the php.ini is but what is the installation tool?

Comment: The TYPO3 install tool is the part of the website where you can do some admin settings. You can find it under "http://domain.tld/typo3/install", or in the backend under "Install tool" in the left menu.